# How to find marginal densities from joint density $f(x,y)$?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

This is the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{\pi} e^{-4x^2 - 6xy - 9y^2}$$

I know that $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\mathrm{d} y$ and similar for $f_Y(y)$.

The following steps give me a constant number and not the correct solution, where exactly is the mistake?

\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&= \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-4x^2 - 6xy - 9y^2}\mathrm{d}x 
\\
&=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(2x+3y)^2}\mathrm{d}x & \mathop{\leftarrow}^\text{subst.} \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}} = 2x+3y\text{ , } \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\sqrt{2}} = \mathrm{d}x\right)
\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}\mathrm{d}t
\\
&= \text{const.}
\end{align}

To get the correct solution I'd have to manipulate the exponent a little bit different but I can't figure out why is this difference necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(2x+3y)^2 = 4 x^2 + 12 x y + 9 y^2$, not $4 x^2 + 6 x y + 9 y^2$.

Comment: Also substituting $t=\sqrt{2}(2x+3\color{red}{y})$ is more than a wee bit iffy.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What's iffy about it?